# Sending HTTP via proxy with haproxy

Tags: haproxy

We have a company proxy (ip:port) and need to send HTTP POST with json payload to the URL like "http://server1.smthng.com/foo". Locally, name could not be resolved, but it is resolved at proxy. I dont understand how to configure haproxy to use proxy "ip:port" and send request without modifying the original URL.

I've tried curl to "http://server1.smthng.com/foo" after setting https_proxy variable from CLI (in linux) and it worked for me, so now I need to replicate same via haproxy.

From curl logs I could see that it first makes a CONNECT to proxy and once connection is there it POSTs the data.

I could be missing some knowledge here regarding tcp tunnels and the answer could be simple really. Anyway, need help.

Answer (score 0):

The question is to be closed with no asnwer. The solution we took is via civetweb htt_proxy parameters.